# Comparing two string iterators always comes out true C++

Tags: c++, string, iterator

So, here's a bit of an odd question that I'm really just having trouble with. I have a list of strings and I'm trying to see if two of them match. So, I have one iterate through and get each string, and another that checks if it has a match. However, it always says that the two are true - even when the first doesn't have a match in the list.

```
for(iterator = tagList.begin(); iterator != tagList.end(); ++iterator)
{
  string theWord = *iterator;
  string currentWord = *iterator;
  if(currentWord[0] == '<' && currentWord[1] != '/')
  {
     bool matchFound = false;

     list<string>::const_iterator it2;
     for(it2 = (++iterator); it2 != tagList.end(); ++it2)
     {
        string temp = *it2;
        if(currentWord.compare(temp) && temp != "")
        {
           fixedString += theWord + ' ';
           matchFound = true;

           cout << "A match was found... Current string: " 
                << fixedString << endl;
           cout << "\tthe matched word was " << *it2 << endl;
           break;
        }
     }
     if(!matchFound)
     {
        currentWord = *iterator;
        currentWord = currentWord.substr(1, currentWord.size() - 2);
        fixedString += currentWord;
        cout << "No match was found... Current string: " << fixedString 
             << endl;
     }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why it's always true?

Comment: `currentWord.compare(temp)` is equivalent to `currentWord != temp` - the opposite of what you say you want. Read the fine manual, the part that describes the return value of `string::compare`.

Comment: While fixing that, `temp != ""` ==> `!temp.empty()`, and you probably want that *first* in your two-part boolean expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with `currentWord.compare(temp)`.  `string::compare()` has a return type of `int` that will be 0 if they are equal (which evaluates to `false`) and a positive or negative numerical value if they are different (which evaluates to `true`).

You want:

```
if((currentWord.compare(temp) == 0) && temp != "") {
...
```

You can read about `string::compare()` here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/